# Testing of algorithms?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a place on Stack Overflow (or anywhere) where I can put my algorithm to the test against programmers?

I have written an algorithm which attempts to remove embed and script tags in every way that I can think of. I'd like to see if I have missed something. What better way than to expose the algorithm to hundreds of bright programmers, all ready to try and break my code?

But before I go and do that I want to make sure that that kind of thing is actually welcome here. I suppose it DOES follow the question-answer format, as:

The question is:
Can my algorithm be tricked:

The answer goes to whoever can come up with the most ways to trick my algorithm.

So, there you have it. Is that allowed? If so/if not, where should I go to try it out?

(Yes, I have been testing this myself nonstop, but I can only think of so much. Hundreds of minds are always better than one)

P.S. Sorry, I somehow failed to mention that this code DOES indeed work. Or so I think. I'd like to test for unforseen edge cases! :)

Comment: If peer review is what you are looking for you could post your _working_ code on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Lots of people there eager to tear your code apart, and some might take the time to test it, but I can't promise that.

Comment: Oh brilliant, @YannisRizos! Please submit that as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Re your edit: I emphasised that your code must be working, not because I assumed it didn't, but because it's the most common reason questions are closed on Code Review. The rule of thumb is: If it's working, Code Review, if it's not, Stack Overflow.

Comment: @YannisRizos Good eye seeing my edits... No worries, I just wanted to avoid future confusion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If peer review is what you are looking for you could post your *working* code on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). From the [site's FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for **sharing code from projects you are working on** for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!

Lots of people there eager to tear your code apart, and some might take the time to test it, but I can't promise that.

Comment: Code Review is awesome, and it beautifully supplements SO, it's sad most people don't even know it exists...

Comment: I will definitely be running alot of my code by it. It would be great to be peer reviewed. I mean, honestly, every time someone corrects you on your algorithms, you LEARN something, instead of blissfully being unware that you could have made your code so much more efficient. Thanks again for this gem! I will accept it when the accept mark allows me to :)